# Why is my Entity Framework site not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and practicing developing an application.

I am currently facing an error where I am using Entity Framework code-first. But when I execute an application my browser is showing the error message as in Pic1 and the code show error in Pic2

Pic1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHKEa.jpg)
Pic2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bARvt.jpg)
Here are the 3 classes that may give you more clarity

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    OdeToFood _db = new OdeToFood();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _db.Restaurants.ToList();

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        //ViewBag.MessageA = "Your application description page.";

        var model = new AboutModel();
        model.Name = "Jimmit Mukesh Raval";
        model.Location = "Mulund";

        ViewBag.Message = "Jimmit Mukesh Raval";

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
}
```

Restaurant.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RestaurantReview> Reviews{ get; set; }
}
}
```

RestaurantReview.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
public class RestaurantReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string RestaurantId { get; set; }
}
}
```

OdeToFood.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
public class OdeToFood:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}
}
```

Can anyone please help me, where am I getting incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add:

```
 public class OdeToFood : DbContext
    {
        public OdeToFood()
         : base("OdeToFood")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
```